# Combat Master Uruks. How can I defeat them?

Tags: middle-earth-shadow-of-mordor

So I was playing Shadow of Mordor and I encountered an Uruk Captain that was a Combat Master.

I just couldn't kill him and he would recuperate health! He would counter everything Executions and even Battle Brands.

How can I defeat these Captains/Warchiefs?

> **URUK IN QUESTION**
>
> I can attack him stealthly BUT that doesn't do much damage to him. Not
>   even with terrorize.
>
> He regains health super-fast and is invulnerable to ranged.

Any special strategy involved? Because he recovered health pretty fast.

Comment: Does the warchief have any fear? A warchief that is in fear would flee the battle and cannot resist grabs. He can then be branded with little effort.

Comment: I'll have to check @wr4ith. I'm trying to find him now.

Comment: You can use the nemesis menu screen to find out the captain's weakness without finding him. My only other suggestion is to make branded captain or warchief kill him. Underhanded sure, but whatever gets the job done right? ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I only encountered a Combat Master once on my playthrough, but it was after I had acquired the Brand skill and one tactic I found to work was to brand nearby Uruks and have them fight him. The damage they themselves did to him was inconsequential, but while he's fighting them, you can get behind him and he's vulnerable to Wraith Stun from behind. Of course once he's stunned you can damage him multiple ways.

Also, as wr4ith says in the comments, if he has a Fear and you exploit it, he's more vulnerable to other tactics.

Comment: Yup that's what I was thinking about. And I poster my own answer but someone downvoted it because god know what. I'll accept this answer.

Answer (score 2):

Wraith Flash normally does the trick. Just build up the combo so you can wraith flash, just don't use the combat execution or combat brand because combat master deflects those. But not Wraith Flash. It takes time, but the higher the combo the more damage it does.

Answer (score 1):

If you already have the Lethal Shadow Strike skill, and provided that the Uruk captain is not invulnerable to ranged attacks, you can keep on using Lethal Shadow strike on him (consumes elf-shots). If you run out of elf-shots, you can build up your hit streak on the Uruk captain (but don't finish the combo), and then combat drain/brand other Uruks.

Comment: Oh you've reminded me about my uruk in question. I'll update the question.

Comment: check out my edit.

Comment: @Lokuzt I'll do further research and try to update my answer. (Need to find an Uruk captain with all those traits.)

Comment: i've updated the question. I was wrong on the uruk about the stealth but I think that doesn't change much. I'll try to provide a screenshot as soon as I get home.

Comment: Do you have branding yet?

Comment: Yes I do @slow_excellence

Comment: I've found the easiest way to defeat them is to combat brand their group and have them fight the captain. I had a ranged captain with no negative stats that would 1-shot me, I didn't kill him until I got the brand ability and turned his allies on him.

Comment: @slow_excellence I guess that's the best way the thing is that I killed his group the time I fought him so next time I fight him I'll maybe try that.

Comment: If you have it, you can also use the stealth special move to get a very quick and cheap kill. It'll still take a few attempts, but he won't know what hit him.

Answer (score 0):

I ran across a tough uruk who was immune to combat finishers, stealth, ranged attacks and a whole heap of other bad effect that made him seem invincible. I had to keep this level 20 ledgendary captian from killing my warcheif and fight off everyone until i could run and tackle him a few times before he went down which was another way to deal with overpowered RNG if anyone runs across the issue.